# New Facebook SDK + Android. Add Image on wall facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, image, facebook-wall

I can not find a working way to send a picture on the wall.
My code is that I do not.

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putByteArray("image", byteArray);
    postParams.putString("message", "A wall picture");

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {

        Log.e("Session", "don t null");
        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,
                HttpMethod.POST);
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
```

Comment: This is done in OnCreate.
Just having gone through this, I did authorize as in the example. And I got a username. But I can not send a picture.

'code'
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {...}

Answer (score 0):

I've never sent pictures from the phone, but from a server using an image link. I'll put this code in case it helps you since most of the logic is similar.

```
final Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("name", getString(R.string.app_name));
parameters.putString("caption", "haha");
parameters.putString("link", "www.google.com");
parameters.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);//I took this one from your code. My key is "picture" instead of "image"
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            new FeedDialogBuilder(EndGameActivity.this, session, parameters).build().show();

            //you can try this one instead of the one above if you want, but both work well
            //Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            //
            //    @Override
            //    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            //        final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            //        new FeedDialogBuilder(EndGameActivity.this, session, parameters).build().show();
            //    }
            //}).executeAsync();
        }

    }
});
```

This code will only work in the last Facebook SDK 3.5 since `Request.newMeRequest` was recently introduced and should be used instead of `Request.executeMeRequestAsync`, which has been deprecated.

Also notice that the key I use is "picture" instead of "image". Maybe that's the problem with your code.

But I do it inside a `onClick` event when the user touch a button. Why do you need it in your `onCreate` method?

Comment: Yes.. I don't think its good practice to use pictures from the phone